# I think my laptop's wifi adapter hardware damaged

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I have wireless WiFi modem, recently my laptop have been acting weird!! When I put my modem 10 cm or more distance away from it, my laptop disconnects. And if I put it on my laptop (next to the touch-pad), the signal strength rises.

I thought its because of windows 10. But I had the same issue when I switch to windows 7 for a test. I just want to know if its software related or hardware.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the antenna may have disconnected. If your laptop is out of warranty, you can open it up and try to attach the antenna. It's a piece of rather stiff wire with a small connector. It looks like this when attached to the WiFi card:

[image: Photo of a WiFi antenna connected to a WiFi card inside a laptop]

([photo source](https://www.flickr.com/photos/rdvortex/16611610442))

Comment: From experience you need quite a bit of force to connect/disconnect it

Comment: A PC doesn't need to be out-of-warranty to open it up, as opening a laptop, or fixing consumer equipment, is Right-to-Repair. If in the US, it's illegal to stipulate anything other _(incl. "[warranty void stickers](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-43724348)")_, violating FTC regulations, the [Magnusson-Moss Warranty Act](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Automotive/Magnusson-Moss%20Warranty%20Act.pdf) [MMWA], and on 2021.07.09 the FTC received orders to fully codify Right-to-Repair, a major win against opponents like Apple and the farm equipment industry.